# Python JSON quoted data for sub class info

Tags: python, json, class

I have some JSON data coming in, and I have it almost working.  The problem is I have a record inside a record, and I want to wrap that data nicely inside a couple Python classes for encoding and decoding.

It works, if I wrap the nested JSON data as a string, but don't really want to do this because it seems like improper JSON.

Example (Works but I don't like it)

```
{"eventData": "{\"itemName\": \"Dflt\"}", "pID": 1}
```

Example (Data I would like to use)

```
{"eventData": {\"itemName\": \"Dflt\"}, "pID": 1}
```

How can I modify my code so I don't have to wrap the sub data in "quotes"

```
import json
from copy import deepcopy


class Event(object):
    __slots__= 'itemName'

    def __init__(self, itemName):
        self.itemName = itemName


    def encode(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['itemName'] = str(self.itemName)               
        return json.dumps(obj)

    def decode(self, json_Str):
        obj = json.loads(json_Str)
        self.itemName = obj['itemName']        



class EventPacket(object):
    __slots__= 'pID', 'eventData' 

    def __init__(self, pID, eventData):
        self.pID = pID
        self.eventData = eventData

    def encode(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['pID'] = int(self.pID)
        obj['eventData'] = self.eventData.encode()


        return json.dumps(obj)

    def decode(self, json_Str):
        obj = json.loads(json_Str)
        self.pID = obj['pID']
        self.eventData = obj['eventData']


defaultEvent = Event('Dflt')
defaultPacket = EventPacket(1, defaultEvent)



packet = deepcopy(defaultPacket)
print 'packet : ', packet.encode()
tempStr = '{"eventData": "{\\"itemName\\": \\"test\\"}", "pID": 2}'
packet.decode(tempStr)
print 'packet : ', packet.encode()
#desired string format
tempStr2 = '{"eventData": {\"itemName\": \"test2\"}, "pID": 3}'
packet.decode(tempStr2)
print 'packet : ', packet.encode()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `{"eventData": {"itemName": "Dflt"}, "pID": 1}}`? As it stands, your desired output is *not* valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I copied what I was getting from my socket connection, and it came through that way, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I didn't say it would make your code magically work, just that the JSON is not valid. :-)

Comment: I am new to JSON, but I think it is just a matter of better formatting standard and my JSON format-er on the other side doesn't do it as nice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it. Implement `to_dict` and `from_dict` functions instead of `encode` and `decode` functions. Perform the JSON encoding at the top level:

```
import json

class Event(object):
    __slots__= 'itemName'

    def __init__(self, itemName):
        self.itemName = itemName

    def to_dict(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['itemName'] = self.itemName
        return obj

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, obj):
        e = cls(obj['itemName'])
        return e

class EventPacket(object):
    __slots__= 'pID', 'eventData' 

    def __init__(self, pID, eventData):
        self.pID = pID
        self.eventData = eventData

    def to_dict(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['pID'] = int(self.pID)
        obj['eventData'] = self.eventData.to_dict()

        return obj

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, obj):
        ep = cls(obj['pID'])
        ep.eventData = Event.from_dict(obj['eventData'])
        return ep

example_event = Event('Dflt')
example_packet = EventPacket(1, example_event)

json_string = json.dumps(example_packet.to_dict())

recovered_example_packet = EventPacket.from_dict(json.loads(json_string))
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost works. Should be obj['pID'] = int(self.pID, self.eventData.to_dict())

Comment: @runfastman: I sincerely doubt that. You can't pass a dict as the second argument to `int`.

Comment: The exact code you gave me does not work with 
newStr = '{"eventData": {\"itemName\": \"test2\"}, "pID": 3}'
recovered_example_packet = EventPacket.from_dict(json.loads(newStr))

Comment: @runfastman: That is not valid JSON. Remove all the backslashes ( \ )